# Unity Download Problem WWW and UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I am trying to download an asset bundle using a URL following is the code I am using:

```
WWW www = new WWW(assetsFilepath);

while (!www.isDone)
{
    Debug.Log("Downloading asset: " + www.progress);
    yield return null;
}

yield return www;

if (www.error == null)               
{                    
    Debug.Log("No Error");
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, assetsFilename);
    FileStream cache = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    cache.Write(www.bytes, 0, www.bytes.Length);
    cache.Close();
}                
else
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
```

`Log Output: Downloading asset: 0`

I am aware that WWW request is obsolete, so I tried the following:

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(assetsFilepath);

while (!www.isDone)
{
    Debug.Log("Downloading asset: " + www.downloadProgress);
    yield return null;
}

yield return www.SendWebRequest();
if (www.error == null)
{
    Debug.Log("No Error");
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, assetsFilename);
    FileStream cache = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    cache.Write(www.downloadHandler.data, 0, www.downloadHandler.data.Length);
    cache.Close();
}
else
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
```

`Log Output : Downloading asset: 0`

Unity: 2018.3.8f

Write Permissions in Player Settings: External SD Card

External Read and Write Permissions are granted

This is the first time I am using UnityWebRequest, I am unable to find why I am getting this every time. Am I missing any step? Or any setting?

Comment: You should wait **after** seinding the request!

Comment: I tried it, but I guess I am still making some mistakes.

Comment: No, in the second code you wait on `www.isDone` before even sending the request (`www.SendWebRequest`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're waiting for the download to be done, before starting it.
Your code should read as follows.

1) Create a request: `UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(assetsFilepath);`

2)

- Send the request and wait for it using one line: `yield return www.SendWebRequest();`
- OR Send it without a yield if you want to track the progress.

  ```
      www.SendWebRequest();
      while (!www.isDone)
      {
          Debug.Log(www.progress);
          yield return null;
      }
  ```

3) Now it finished, wait for the download handler to finish processing the data:

```
while(!www.downloadHandler.isDone)
   yield return null;
```

4) Now enjoy your downloaded data at `www.downloadHandler.data`

Comment: Do you mean this? @Tenretni

`UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(assetsFilepath);
www.SendWebRequest();
while (!www.isDone)
{
    Debug.Log("Downloading asset: " + www.downloadProgress);
    yield return null;
}
while (!www.downloadHandler.isDone)
    yield return null;
if (www.error == null)
{
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, assetsFilename);
    FileStream cache = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    cache.Write(www.downloadHandler.data, 0, www.downloadHandler.data.Length);
    cache.Close();
}`

Comment: This `while (!www.downloadHandler.isDone) yield return null;` is redundant since you already wait for `isDone` in the loop before..

Comment: @derHugo we're waiting for the downloadhandler, not the download process, I've experienced sometimes when the 'downloadHandler' 'isDone' flag is false even though the request 'isDone' was true, this is because depending on the type of downloadHandler like texture or FileDownloadHandler, it can take a millisecond after the download 'isDone'.

Comment: @Tenretni okey why not ^^ Never experienced this behavior before though .. but as said it's not wrong .. in worst case it just yields one more frame ;)

Comment: This worked `UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(assetsFilepath);
www.SendWebRequest();
while (!www.isDone)
{
    Debug.Log("Downloading asset: " + www.downloadProgress);
    yield return null;
}
if (www.error == null)
{
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, assetsFilename);
    FileStream cache = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    cache.Write(www.downloadHandler.data, 0, www.downloadHandler.data.Length);
    cache.Close();
}`

Thanks @derHugo and @Tenretni

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(assetsFilepath);
www.SendWebRequest();
while (!www.isDone)
{
    Debug.Log("Downloading asset: " + www.downloadProgress);
}
if (www.error == null)
{
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, assetsFilename);
    FileStream cache = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    cache.Write(www.downloadHandler.data, 0, www.downloadHandler.data.Length);
    cache.Close();
}
```